# Triple Integral in Spherical Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve the triple integral of $3x^2 + 3y^2 + 3z^2$ in spherical coordinates, with rho from 1 to 2, theta from 0 to 2$\pi$, and $\phi$ from 0 to $\pi /4$.

Here's how I'm solving it: First I convert the expression to spherical coordinates: $3p^2\sin^2\phi\, cos^2\theta + 3p^2sin^2\phi\, sin^2\theta + 3p^2cos^2\phi$. This is then multiplied by the Jacobean $sin(\phi)*p^2$

I integrate over p. This gives me $3/5  p^5$ over the interval 1 to 2, which leaves me with 18.6 I integrate over $\theta$, which amounts to throwing a 2pi in, giving me $37.2\cdot \int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\pi cos^2(\phi)*sin(\phi) + 1)$.

This is where I know I've gone wrong. I integrate this and get $\pi/4 + cos^3(\phi)/3$. Everyone else online seems to simply get $-cos(\phi)$. This is the only spot our answers differ. Something about my integral is wrong but I don't know what.

Comment: Your integrand should only have $\rho$, no $\theta$.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrand becomes

$3x^2 + 3y^2 + 3z^2 \mapsto 3 \rho^2$ times the Jacobian. This means you integrate

$$\int_{\rho=1}^{\rho=2} \int_{\phi=0}^{\phi= \frac{\pi}{4} } \int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2 \pi} 3 \rho^4 \sin \phi \> d\theta d\phi d\rho$$

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me<sup>1</sup> that you simplified

$$ \sin^2 \phi \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2\phi \sin^2 \theta \mapsto 1 $$

when you should have

$$ \sin^2 \phi \cos^2 \theta + \sin^2\phi \sin^2 \theta = \sin^2\phi $$

---

Alternatively, you may have also recognized from the get-go that

$$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \rho^2 $$

from the definition of $\rho$.

---

<sup>1</sup> I am just making an educated guess based on your description of what you did; short of you showing every line of your work I cannot be sure.